# Rank with ties in python when tie breaker is random

Tags: python, r, pandas, scipy

In R , way to break ties randomly when using the rank function is simple:

```
rank(my_vec, ties.method = "random")
```

However, though both scipy ([scipy.stats.rankdata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html)) and pandas ([pandas.Series.rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html)) have ranking functions, none of them suggest a method that break ties randomly.
Is there a simple way to use a framework in python that has this feature? Given that list order has to remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas' rank allows for these methods:

```
method : {'average', 'min', 'max', 'first', 'dense'}
    * average: average rank of group
    * min: lowest rank in group
    * max: highest rank in group
    * first: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array
    * dense: like 'min', but rank always increases by 1 between groups
```

To "simply" accomplish your goal we can use `'first'` after having randomized the Series.

Assume my series is named `my_vec`

```
my_vec.sample(frac=1).rank(method='first')
```

You can then put it back in the same order it was with

```
my_vec.sample(frac=1).rank(method='first').reindex_like(my_vec)
```

---

**Example Runs**

```
my_vec = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

**Trial 1**

```
my_vec.sample(frac=1).rank(method='first').reindex_like(my_vec)

0    2.0  <- I expect this and
1    4.0
2    6.0
3    1.0  <- this to be first ranked
4    3.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

**Trial 2**

```
my_vec.sample(frac=1).rank(method='first').reindex_like(my_vec)

0    1.0  <- Still first ranked
1    3.0
2    6.0
3    2.0  <- but order has switched
4    4.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```